# Rewriting path with http-proxy-middleware

Tags: node.js, proxy, gulp

Trying to rewrite path of request with http-proxy-middleware. But trouble is that when i am writing such code:

```
proxyMiddleware('/service/api', {target: 'http://192.168.70.99:8078/'});
```

It means that path like /service/api/export/1 will be redirected to http://192.168.70.99:8078/service/api/export/1; But I need to redirect it to http://192.168.70.99:8078/export/1. How can I do that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can pass the [`pathRewrite`](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#options) opiton and inside it use regex pattern to remove the path that you don't need:

```
proxyMiddleware('/service/api', {
  target: 'http://192.168.70.99:8078/',
  pathRewrite: {
    '^/service/api':'' //remove /service/api
  }
});
```

Comment: it doesn't help:|
pathRewrite didn't remove 'sevice/api' from path

Comment: Also make sure to update http-proxy-middleware. pathRewrite functionality was added in version 0.1.0