# How to rewrite request path using http-proxy-middleware in a react app?

Tags: node.js, create-react-app, http-proxy-middleware

I am using http-proxy-middleware in my react app, where I have a setup like this:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    "/api/v1",
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: "https:test.com/",
      changeOrigin: true
    })
  );
};
```

Some api requests of my applications has request url as:
**http://localhost:3000/products-and-details/api/v1/proxy/trend/api/v1/listProducts**
which I want to change it to:
**http://localhost:3000/api/v1/proxy/trend/api/v1/listProducts.**

To achieve this I am modifying request paths before requests are send to the target using pathRewrite as below:

```
pathRewrite: {
        '^/products-and-details': ''
      }
```

However this doesn't seem to work and the request url remains the same with no changes. Can anyone please help to point out what am I doing wrong here?

**Edit:** My http-proxy-middleware dependency has a version **^2.0.3**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31394321/1808494 "Also make sure to update http-proxy-middleware. pathRewrite functionality was added in version 0.1.0"

Comment: @Aron Please look at the edit for version of  http-proxy-middleware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My senior colleague helped me to fix this. It seemed that the request, **http://localhost:3000/products-and-details/api/v1/proxy/trend/api/v1/listProducts** was not at all intercepted by the proxy. Hence, to intercept those requests we have to make sure to include it in the [**context**](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#createproxymiddlewarecontext-config) for our proxy middleware.

So, in  my case it was as described below:

```
app.use(["/api/v1", "/products-and-details/api/v1"])
```

And then use **[PathRewrite](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/blob/master/recipes/pathRewrite.md#rewrite-paths)** to modify request paths before the actual request is made to server as depicted below:

```
pathRewrite: {"/products-and-details": ""}
```